# Is this question appropriate to the site?

Tags: discussion, questions, off-topic

I wonder whether the following question belongs in SO or better suited for code review, the example is abstract:

I have implemented X in a certain way:

```
DoSomeThings();
in = some << way;
```

is there a better way to achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems like the very definition of "code review" to me.

"Is there a better way to do this" is a subset of "look at this code and tell me what's done poorly, what's done well and how it could be improved."

Also, this seems to fit well with "Best practices and design pattern usage in your code," which is [explicitly on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) at Code Review SE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will go there. Yet, does it fit SO as well? "a software algorithm" in the SO FAQ.

Comment: It's borderline. It's about an algorithm, yes, but you don't really have a problem. Fixing something that's broken is different than taking something that works and making it work even better.

Comment: You're the first in years to tell me that I don't really have a problem :) And I get your comment, thanks!

Answer (score -3):

I would like to see that type of question on SO.

Comment: I very much dislike when I see that type of question on StackOverflow, especially knowing that CodeReview is out there.